# Get an image for each Woocommerce product tag using Taxonomy Images plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I'm developing a plugin for Woocommerce and I use the [Taxonomy Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/) plugin to add image feature for Woocommerce product tag custom taxonomy.

Now I am trying to show for each product the product tag name with his coresponding image in a function. But may be I failed something because I see all tags and not only the tags for a specific product.

To get the product ID I have tried with `global $product;` but it's not working.

This is my code:

```
function woo_idoneo_tab_content() {

    $id = get_the_ID();

    $terms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '', array('taxonomy' => 'product_tag', 'id' => $id, ) );

        if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {

            print '<div class="container">';

            foreach ( (array) $terms as $term) {

            $url = get_term_link ($term->slug, 'product_tag' , $id);


            print '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">';
            print '<div class="card">';
            print '<div class="card-img-top"><a href="'.$url.'">' . wp_get_attachment_image( $term->image_id, 'medium' ) . '</a></div>';
            print '<div class="card-body">';        
            print "<h5 class='card-title'><a class='btn btn-primary' href='{$url}'>{$term->name}</a></h5>";

            }

            print '</div>';
            print '</div>';
            print '</div>';
        }
            print '</div>';

    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to put code directly on the question, not only a link to a pastebin. It's the rule of this site. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
$terms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '', array('taxonomy' => 'product_tag', 'id' => $id, ) );
```

you should use:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_tag' );
```

Now the [Taxonomy Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/) plugin stores the taxonomy images in `wp_otion` table. To get that data you will use:

```
$custom_taxonomy_images = get_option( 'taxonomy_image_plugin' ); // Array of term Ids / Image Ids pairs
```

So your revisited code is now:

```
function woo_idoneo_tab_content() {
    // Check that plugin is active, if not we exit.
    if( ! is_plugin_active( 'taxonomy-images/taxonomy-images.php' ) ) return;

    $taxonomy = 'product_tag';
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy ); // Terms for this post
    $custom_taxonomy_images = get_option( 'taxonomy_image_plugin' ); // Plugin images data

    if ( empty( $terms ) ) return; // If no terms found, we exit.

    ## -- HTML Output below -- ##

    echo '<div class="container">';
    // Loop through each term in this post for the defined taxonomy
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $attachment_id = $custom_taxonomy_images[intval($term->term_id)]; // Get image Attachement ID
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'medium' ); // Get image to be displayed
        $url = get_term_link( $term->term_id, $taxonomy ); // Get term URL
        ?>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-img-top">
                    <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><?php echo $image; ?></a>
                    </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
                    </h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks, it's works fine.

One question, what's the intval parameters ?